# what is the most memory efficient datastructure for maintaining a sordted <5k list of integers?

Tags: algorithm, list, sorting, data-structures, tree

I have many lists of sorted integers, all of them less than 3600 items each. I'd like to keep them in memory as much as possible, so I'm looking for a space efficient datastructure.

Most common operations will be inserts, membership testing and range queries.

the integers will be mostly in the 1 through 10 billion-range, though in theory there could be some corner cases where the integers will be much lower.

I've been looking at skiplists, which are quite nice, but I feel there might be more efficient structures out there.

Comment: arrays don't let me keep it sorted when inserting, right?

Comment: Well... You can insert an element in an already sorted array so that it goes in the right place.

Comment: How many lists? What's the range of the integers? Are there duplicates? Is there a required time complexity on the operations, or just as fast as possible? Can anything be said for how often which elements are accessed (making writing to disc a possibility)?

Comment: Are these US phone numbers perchance?

Comment: no they're not. they're actually auto-increment id's from another table which is currently in this range. Since I'm mostly storing current ids (last 3600) I expect the numbers to be in this range, gove or take an outlier which could point to earlier ids.

Comment: A slip list is a really good choice for a sorted list. Not sure about subrange queries, though.

Comment: whats a slip list, couldn't find any info on it anywhere?

Comment: @JimMischel I presume you meant "skip list"?

Comment: Yeah, I meant skip list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This really depends on the access pattern and the proportion of lookups with respect to modifications. When lookups are much more common than modifications (in your case, inserts apparently), which is quite common, you can actually get away with sorted arrays which will give you optimal memory efficiency.

If the inserts are actually more common, sorted arrays probably won't do, and you will have to resort to more complicated data structures. B-trees sound like a possible candidate given that they pack many nodes together, and thus do not suffer from the linkage overhead as much as AVLs, skip-lists or red-black trees.

I think it would be similarly interesting to investigate radix trees, especially if there happens to be a lot of successive integers in your lists, because such ranges would get "compressed" by the radix tree.

It is worth noting that a bloom filter can help further optimize your membership queries. They are, in a way, the most space-efficient data structures for membership queries, but being probabilistic, you can only use them in combination with some other deterministic data structure, unless of course you are allowed to return incorrect answers :-).

Comment: thanks a lot, the radix trie is something I hadn't considered yet, seems interesting!

Comment: I don't think bloom filters will result in space-efficiency when used with a deterministic secondary data structure. Won't you use more space than the secondary data structure, thus it would be more space efficient to use just that structure? And range queries won't work.

Comment: Well that is basically what I said - that they can "help further optimize your membership queries".What I'm saying next is merely pointing out that they can be seen as the most space-efficient data structure for membership queries. I never said it would be more space-efficient to use a bloom filter in combination with a deterministic data structure, this obviously cannot be true, unless you think it's possible to have data structures with negative memory usage? ;-)